# How to convert rdd / data frame / dataset to String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

How to convert rdd / data frame / dataset to String / List in spark scala without collect

Comment: Question does not really add up imho.

Comment: You probably need to explain what you are trying to achieve here. converting it to list you will need to bring everything to one JVM because unline RDD's they can not exist in multiple places. hence it will effectively be a collect.

Comment: Can you explain what is your use case? What do you want to do whit those Strings? Write them to a file perhaps?

Comment: i have dataframe which contains table_name along with data. each table will have different table structure. i need to loop a distinct table from the dataframe and need to write to respective table so i have the below code       val tablename:Array[String] = df1.select("msgname").distinct().rdd.map(row=>row.getString(0).trim).collect

    tablename.foreach{table =>
      df1.write.saveastable(s"$table")
      
    }

Comment: is there a better way to do without making a collect at first for getting table name

Answer (score 1):

Spark DataFrame/Dataset/RDD are distributed a collection of data, On the other hand, List is a collection and is not distributed.

Hence the only way to convert an RDD to a List would be to bring all the partitions of an RDD to a single JVM and convert it to a List. and That will effectively be collect operation.

In a nutshell, collect is the only appropriate way to do what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are trying to make each column in the row as a string separated by a delimiter

## to convert rdd rows to a string

```
val out_rdd = rdd.map(x => x.mkString(",")
```

## to convert dataframe/dataset rows to string

```
val out_rdd = df.rdd.map(x => x.mkString(",")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: For converting RDD[array[string]] to array[string] can we do it without collect?

Comment: I believe it is not possible.. if you try array_rdd.toString() you will get only string.

Comment: i have dataframe which contains table_name along with data. each table will have different table structure. i need to loop a distinct table from the dataframe and need to write to respective table so i have the below code       val tablename:Array[String] = df1.select("msgname").distinct().rdd.map(row=>row.getString(0).trim).collect

    tablename.foreach{table =>
      df1.write.saveastable(s"$table")
      
    }

Comment: is there a better way to do without making a collect at first for getting table name

Comment: what are trying to to do is filter your data based on some value and store the data as table with the same value---
def saveTable(filter_value:String) {
df.filter(col("tablename")=== filter_value).write.saveAsTable(filter_value)
} --hope this helps